# WPF threads - can't access property/field

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094911/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

I'm writing some thread handling in my app:

```
BackgroundWorkers()
{
    WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Loop));
    WorkerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    WorkerThread.Start();
}
```

The called method is this one:

```
    public static void Loop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (BackgroundWorkersTick != null)
            {
                BackgroundWorkersTick();
            }
            Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
        }
    }
```

in the "client" I use it this way:

```
BackgroundWorkers.BackgroundWorkersTick += new BackgroundWorkers.BackgroundWorkersTickHandler(Refresh);
...
private void Refresh()
{
    ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables = GameClient.ListTables();
    tablesListView1.SetItems(ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables);
    tablesListView1.Refresh();
}
```

TableListView inside has a method:

```
    public void Refresh() { ListItemContainer.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)BindItems); }

    private void BindItems()
    {
        ListItemContainer.Children.Clear();
        foreach (TablesListViewItem item in items)
        {
            ListItemContainer.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

iItems is defined as:

```
private List<TablesListViewItem> items;
```

In the line

> ListItemContainer.Children.Add(item);

I'm getting exception of InvalidOperationException with message: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

This whole code goes for WPF. I tried to switch to property, but no effect. I thought that the Dispatcher will do the work... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually need the STA?

Comment: Without it, the app crash with message that only STA can get access to UI controls (or sth like this)

Comment: Try fetching the dispatcher like this - Application.Current.Dispatcher

Answer (score 2):

Change the following lines

```
private void Refresh()
{
    ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables = GameClient.ListTables();
    tablesListView1.SetItems(ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables);
    tablesListView1.Refresh();
}
```

To

```
private void Refresh()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>
    {
      ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables = GameClient.ListTables();
      tablesListView1.SetItems(ViewDataCollection.GetData<TableViewData>().Tables);
      tablesListView1.Refresh();
    }));
}
```